# How to pass html tags as part of JavaScript argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First time having to do this so please bear with me.

I've created a helper function that allows for an English and a French version of text for a React application. Example:

```
{outputEnFr(
  "Currently Availability:",
  "Disponibilité actuelle:",
  this.props.lang
)}
```

Where the English text above is in the helper function ("Currently Availability:"), I need to pass in the below html:

```
<p>
   <strong>Yes</strong> = available and ready in our yard
</p>
<p>
   <strong>No</strong> = currently on rent, on contract
   or being serviced. Please contact us to reserve this
   unit.
</p>
```

How can I pass in this html block of code into the JavaScript argument above in the English area of the helper function?

What I've tried but won't work:

```
{outputEnFr(
"
  <p>
     <strong>Yes</strong> = available and ready in our yard
  </p>
  <p>
     <strong>No</strong> = currently on rent, on contract
     or being serviced. Please contact us to reserve this
     unit.
  </p>
",
"Disponibilité actuelle:",
this.props.lang
)}
```

Comment: It's totally not clear, What you want to achieve and what you've tried. At least try to explain the question properly.

Comment: @DeC edited for more clarity, I did explain the question properly.

Comment: I would have to agree that it's not clear: what do you expect to happen?  Instead of what you expect, what do you see-- do you get an error, for example?  More details would be helpful to those who want to help!

Comment: You are just passing some strings here.  The problem is likely that your outputEnFr function doesn't like HTML jammed in to the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy is very weird. If you need to translate your app, just use react-18next, or any similar library (Talkr, etc.) rather than passing full html blocks as parameters. So it would like this:

```js
 <p><strong>{t("yes")}</strong> {t("yard.availability")}</p>
 <p> <strong>{t("no")}</strong>{t("rent.contact")}</p>
```